# changing a field in the model when retrieving the detail object in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model as follows:

```
class PPost(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name='posts4thisowner',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    furnished = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Is Furnished", default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description", max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    viewnum=models.IntegerField(verbose_name="view num", default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('timestamp',)
```

and my detail view is as like this:

```
class PPostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = PPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PPostSerializer
    name = 'ppost-detail'
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        custompermission.IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )
```

which will be used in the following url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:pk>', views.PPostDetail.as_view(), name=views.PPostDetail.name),
]
```

now I need to be able to increase viewnum,one of the fields in the model representing viewing number of the a post to be increased by one whenever the request.GET is called; I was wondering how can I achieve this in my view.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the **`dispatch()`** method of the view class, see the example

```
class PPostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = PPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PPostSerializer
    name = 'ppost-detail'
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        custompermission.IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ppost_object = self.get_object()
        ppost_object.viewnum += 1
        ppost_object.save()
        return super(PPostDetail, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

From the Django Doc, the [**`dispatch()`** method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch)

> The view part of the view – the method that accepts a request argument
>   plus arguments, and returns a HTTP response.
>
> The default implementation will inspect the HTTP method and attempt to
>   delegate to a method that matches the HTTP method; a GET will be
>   delegated to get(), a POST to post(), and so on.
>
> By default, a HEAD request will be delegated to get(). If you need to
>   handle HEAD requests in a different way than GET, you can override the
>   head() method. See Supporting other HTTP methods for an example.